# Putting SO (shared object) file in android build path showing red exclamation mark on project

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, android-library, shared-libraries

I have an `SO` file which is compiled with `GCC` compiler with command -

> gcc -mandroid -c ret.c

Here is the [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110577076/libret.so) to the SO file.

Comment: Are you using ndk-build?

Comment: No I am using Linux command line to make the SO file.

Comment: No, are you using ndk-build to compile your Android C/C++ code?

Comment: Ok so for that I have to use NDK build ?

Comment: Check out the `docs` folder in your ndk installation, specifically `ANDROID-MK.html` and `NDK-BUILD.html` to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the .so file in your libs/armeabi/ subdirectory, and it should automatically be included as part of your build. Don’t mention it in LOCAL_SRC_FILES, as it’s not a source file.